# Configure pointer focus properties of Matlab's command window

Tags: matlab, focus

- I'm running Matlab 2013a, under Linux, using Xmonad (using the XMonad.Config.Xfce package).
- This problem occurs whether the command window is docked or not.
- The command window prompt does not get the keyboard focus unless the pointer is located
  over the command window.

Is there a way to get the Matlab command window to have focus behaviour just like other normal windows, like a terminal?

Most important: I'd like to have the keyboard focus follow the window focus,
and not require any special positioning of the pointer, so that I can just "<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>" around my windows and have the command window get the keyboard focus.  All of the resources I've found so far relate to programmatic control of focus; I'm just trying to improve my user experience in an interactive session.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your questions: When does your command window get the focus? When do you want it to get focus? I can change window settings for the operating system. So when I un-dock the command window, it is in focus as long as the pointer is located over it. If I move the pointer over the editor, it is in focus instead. If the window is docked, I have to click. However, I can turn this behaviour off for the OS.

Comment: @Schorsch I want to navigate between my windows using the keyboard, and not have to rely on moving/clicking-with the mouse to set the focus.  Matlab is not cooperating.

Comment: `Alt + Tab` & un-docked windows works for me - I assume it doesn't for you?

Comment: I can't reproduce this...Works like it should. You are sure it's properly undocked, e.g., a standalone window in its own tile with its own window title etc.?

Comment: If it's not reproducible, this question should probably be closed; it might depend on the details of my Xmonad configuration.

Answer (score 1):

To get keyboard focus on the Command Window, include the following in your `xmonad.hs`

```
import XMonad.Hooks.SetWMName
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers
```

and configure your `ManageHook` as follows

```
myManageHook = composeAll . concat $
    [ [appName =? a --> doCenterFloat | a <- myFloatAS ]
    , (your other hooks)
    ] where
        myFloatAS = ["MATLAB"]
```

Finally, include `setWMName "LG3D"` in your `startupHook`. See [here](https://bitbucket.org/joko/dotfiles/commits/77661e91afd97b955b5dd569d33a14db4560b220#chg-xmonad/xmonad.symlink/xmonad.hs) for a full `xmonad.hs` configuration which uses this (this is where I found the solution). If you have other Java apps that don't get focus as they should you can add them to the `myFloatAS` list.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem in the built-in java.

If i run:

```
export MATLAB_JAVA=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre
matlab -desktop
```

Matlab works as expected.

I ran into this problem, running MATLAB2014a. I set up setWMName "LG3D" but still i couldn't get focus on my window. I had to click on the focused window to get the cursor, and sometimes the situation was even worse and I had to click on random places till i get my cursor back. This wouldn't happen on MATLAB2010. What worked for me was to use the native version of java as describe above.

In the end, i used the following bash script to start matlab8:

```
#!/bin/bash
export MATLAB_JAVA=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/
/usr/local/bin/matlab8 -desktop -nosplash
```